# Java String.split() sometimes giving blank strings

Tags: java, regex, string, split

I'm making a text based dice roller. It takes in strings like "2d10+5" and returns a string as a result of the roll(s). My problem is showing up in the tokenizer that splits the string into useful parts for me to parse into information.

`String[] tokens = message.split("(?=[dk\\+\\-])");`

This is yielding strange, unexpected results. I don't know exactly what is causing them. It could be the regex, my misunderstanding, or Java just being Java. Here's what's happening:

- `3d6+4` yields the string array `[3, d6, +4]`. This is correct.
- `d%` yields the string array `[d%]`. This is correct.
- `d20` yields the string array `[d20]`. This is correct.
- `d%+3` yields the string array `[, d%, +3]`. This is incorrect.
- `d20+2` yields the string array `[, d20, +2]`. This is incorrect.

In the fourth and fifth example, something strange is causing an extra empty string to appear at the front of the array. It's not the lack of number at the front of the string, as other examples disprove that. It's not the presence of the percentage sign, nor the the plus sign.

For now I'm just continuing through the for loop on blank strings, but that feels sorta like a band-aid solution. Does anyone have any idea what causes the blank string at the front of the array? How can I fix it?

Comment: This is no longer the behavior.  I believe it was changed in Java 8.  There is a new paragraph in the javadoc that says "A zero-width match at the beginning however never produces such empty leading substring."

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Digging through the source code, I got the exact issue behind this behaviour.

The `String.split()` method internally uses `Pattern.split()`. The split method before returning the resulting array checks for the last matched index or if there is actually a match. If the last matched index is `0`, that means, your pattern matched just an empty string at the beginning of the string or didn't match at all, in which case, the returned array is a single element array containing the same element.

Here's the source code:

```
public String[] split(CharSequence input, int limit) {
        int index = 0;
        boolean matchLimited = limit > 0;
        ArrayList<String> matchList = new ArrayList<String>();
        Matcher m = matcher(input);

        // Add segments before each match found
        while(m.find()) {
            if (!matchLimited || matchList.size() < limit - 1) {
                String match = input.subSequence(index, m.start()).toString();
                matchList.add(match);

                // Consider this assignment. For a single empty string match
                // m.end() will be 0, and hence index will also be 0
                index = m.end();
            } else if (matchList.size() == limit - 1) { // last one
                String match = input.subSequence(index,
                                                 input.length()).toString();
                matchList.add(match);
                index = m.end();
            }
        }

        // If no match was found, return this
        if (index == 0)
            return new String[] {input.toString()};

        // Rest of them is not required
```

If the last condition in the above code - `index == 0`, is true, then the single element array is returned with the input string.

Now, consider the cases when the `index` can be `0`.

1. When there is no match at all. (As already in the comment above that condition)
2. If the match is found at the beginning, and the length of matched string is `0`, then the value of index in the `if` block (inside the `while` loop) -

   ```
   index = m.end();
   ```

   will be 0. The only possible match string is an *empty string* (length = 0). Which is exactly the case here. And also there shouldn't be any further matches, else `index` would be updated to a different index.

So, considering your cases:

- For `d%`, there is just a single match for the pattern, before the first `d`. Hence the index value would be `0`. But since there isn't any further matches, the index value is not updated, and the `if` condition becomes `true`, and returns the single element array with original string.
- For `d20+2` there would be two matches, one before `d`, and one before `+`. So index value will be updated, and hence the `ArrayList` in the above code will be returned, which contains the empty string as a result of split on delimiter which is the first character of the string, as already explained in @Stema's answer.

So, to get the behaviour you want (that is split on delimiter only when it is not at the beginning, you can add a negative look-behind in your regex pattern):

```
"(?<!^)(?=[dk+-])"  // You don't need to escape + and hyphen(when at the end)
```

this will split on empty string followed by your character class, but not preceded by the beginning of the string.

---

Consider the case of splitting the string `"ad%"` on regex pattern - `"a(?=[dk+-])"`. This will give you an array with the first element as empty string. What the only change here is, the empty string is replaced with `a`:

```
"ad%".split("a(?=[dk+-])");  // Prints - `[, d%]`
```

Why? That's because the length of the matched string is `1`. So the index value after the first match - `m.end()` wouldn't be `0` but `1`, and hence the single element array won't be returned.

Comment: Wow, thats a detailed analyses, thanks for the explanation. I was only at the point that I recognized, it depends on the amount of matches.

Comment: @stema. Actually that was a good question by OP. Never thought of this. Learnt something new today :)

Comment: Wow, thanks! That completely explains it. Great answer. Both solved my problem and helped me learn.

Comment: Could we call it a bug?

Comment: @assylias. Possibly. But I guess it's the rarest of the rare case, that it couldn't be found till now. But since it's not the case where the source code is behaving in a way it is not intended to. But I agree that it should have been mentioned in the Javadoc too. I'm not really sure whether I should post it as bug or not.

Comment: The docs state very clearly how *trailing* empty tokens are dropped by default, and a mechanism is provided to override that behavior.  Yet there's no mention of how *leading* empty tokens are handled, and no way to change that behavior.  Add to that the inconsistent behavior for inputs that contain different numbers of tokens, and yes, that's definitely a bug.

Answer (score 5):

I was surprised that it does not happen for case 2 and 3, so the real question here is

> Why is there **NO** empty string at the start for "d20" and "d%"?

as Rohit Jain explained in his detailed analyses, this happens, when there is only one match found at the start of the string and the match.end index is 0. (This can only happen, when only a lookaround assertion is used for finding the match).

The problem is, that `d%+3` starts with a char you are splitting on. So your regex matches before the first character and you get an empty string at the start.

You can add a lookbehind, to ensure that your expression is not matching at the start of the string,so that it is not splitted there:

```
String[] tokens = message.split("(?<!^)(?=[dk\\+\\-])");
```

`(?<!^)` is a lookbehind assertion that is true, when it is not at the start of the string.

Comment: +1 because your solution works - but `d20` also starts with a char that the op is splitting on so the reason you give is probably not the right one.

Comment: So is `d%`. But no empty string is there in that cse.

Comment: OK, those teststrings shouldn't deliver different results, I need to startup eclipse and check.

Comment: Good answer for `lookbehind`, didn't think about

Comment: Your solution did it. Sticking the (?<!^) in front solved the problem, although I'm still not completely sure why it showed up some times and not other times.

Comment: @CoreyNoel, I tested at the moment. I can confirm your result, but I don't know why it is.

Comment: @CoreyNoel stema It's all in the source code. I have explained in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend simple matching rather than splitting:

```
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("([1-9]*)(d[0-9%]+)([+-][0-9]+)?").matcher(string);
if(matcher.matches()) {
    String first = matcher.group(1);
    // etc
}
```

No guarantee for the regex, but I think it will do...