# Splitting string on first character makes first element null. How to get around this?

Tags: java, split

So let's say I have this string:

```
+-5
```

I'm splitting at the + sign into an array. My first element is null and my second element is -5. How can I get around this and make the first element just -5?

Edit: Here's some of my code:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.print("Enter polynomial function: ");

String function = sc.nextLine();
function = function.replaceAll("-", "+-").replaceAll(" ", "");

String[] terms = function.split("\\+");
```

I'm trying to get the coefficients of the polynomial by first replacing all - with +-

```
-5x^2 + 3x -2
+-5x^2 +3x +-2
Now it should split wherever there is a + sign.
First element is null, second element is -5x^2, third element 3x and fourth is -2
```

Comment: You only describe what you are doing. Show us the code that does it.

Comment: Your first element is not null,its empty string. From [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String) you will get an empty string at the beginning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One relatively simple way to solve the problem is to create your own function that checks the first character of the String manually:

```
public static String[] splitPlus(String input) {
    String toSplit = (!input.isEmpty() && input.charAt(0) == '+') ? input.substring(1) : input;
    return toSplit.split("\\+");
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. This works, all I had to change was + to \\+.

Answer (score 0):

`split()` method perform the splitting in a special way.It creates the array of substrings of the patterns finishing with the character specified in the brackets of split,so in your case ,there is nothing in front of '`+`' hence it returns empty string at the zero index of the array returned.To perform your desired operation,

- Either you can have a check for empty string there
- Or start from the first index of the array returned

See this [Java String.split() sometimes giving blank strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18870699/java-string-split-sometimes-giving-blank-strings) too

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try [commons lang](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/) library's [StringUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html):

```
String[] terms = StringUtils.split(function, '+');
for (String term : terms) {
    System.out.println(term);
}
```

Output:

```
-5x^2
3x
-2
```

It also strips the spaces.