# Split String To Get Word Separators

Tags: java, regex

I want to find store all the separators between the words in a sentence which could be spaces, newlines.

Say I have the following String:

```
String text = "hello, darkness   my old friend.\nI've   come to you again\r\nasd\n 123123";

String[] separators = text.split("\\S+");
```

Output: `[,  ,    ,  ,  , 
,    ,  ,  ,  , 
, 
 ]`

So I split on anything but a space it is returning an empty separator at first and the rest are good. Why the empty string at first tho?

Also, I would like to split on periods and commas. But I don't know how to do that meaning that `".\n"` is a separator.

Wanted Output for the above String:

```
 separators = {", ", "   ", " ", " ", ".\n", "   ", " ", " ", " ", "\r\n", "\n "}
```

or

```
 separators = {",", " ", "   ", " ", " ", ".", "\n", "   ", " ", " ", " ", "\r\n", "\n "}
```

Comment: For the dot and newline, you'll need to escape them, e.g. `\\.` and `\\n`

Comment: You could try using [StringTokenizer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.html).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java String.split() sometimes giving blank strings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18870699/java-string-split-sometimes-giving-blank-strings). Just for your first question, but there you go, a perfect reason to only *ask* one at a time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
String[] separators = text.split("[\\w']+");
```

This defines non-separators as "word chars" and/or apostrophes.

This does leave a leading blank in the result array, which is not possible to avoid, except by removing the leading word first:

```
String[] separators = text.replaceAll("^[\\w']+", "").split("[\\w']+");
```

You may consider adding the hyphen to the character class, if you consider hyphenated words (example in the previous sentence) as one word, ie

```
String[] separators = text.split("[\\w'-]+");
```

See [live demo](https://ideone.com/kP06KM).

Answer (score 0):

I think this can also work correctly:

`String[] separators = text.split("\\w+");`

Answer (score 0):

If think it's more easy to use the `.find()` method to obtain the desired result:

```
String text = "hello, darkness   my old friend.\nI've   come to you again\r\nasd\n 123123";

String pat = "[\\s,.]+"; // add all that you need to the character class
Matcher m = Pattern.compile(pat).matcher(text);

List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

while( m.find() ) {
    list.add(m.group());
}

// the result is already stored in "list" but if you
// absolutely want to store the result in an array, just do:

String[] result = list.toArray(new String[0]);
```

This way you avoid the empty string problem at the beginning.